# Calling The Same Function Repeatedly In Python

Tags: python

I've written a little function with a replace() to clean up redirect files to strip out the logic and essentially leave in the pure English.

So far I've got:

```
def redir_cleanup(searchFor, replaceWith):
    inputFile = open('input', 'r')
    outputFile = open('output', 'w+')   

    for line in inputFile:
        print "Replacing %s with '%s'" % (searchFor, replaceWith)
        outputFile.write(line.replace(searchFor, replaceWith))

redir_cleanup("RedirectMatch permanent ", "")
redir_cleanup("RewriteRule ^", "")
redir_cleanup(" [L,R=301]", "")
redir_cleanup("RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search\=(", "")
redir_cleanup(")$ [NC]", "")
redir_cleanup("\+", " ")
redir_cleanup("[NC,OR]", "")
redir_cleanup("RewriteRule ^.* ", "")
```

But it only strips the top call, do I need to loop them somehow?

Comment: I haven't checked to see if this solves your problem, but it may be useful to close your files at the end of the function. (or use `with`).

Comment: Thanks, it didn't solve the issue, but I forgot the closes in this rewrite.  I've been playing with it and written it a few times :)

Comment: You need to apply each filter to each line in the file. So you got this inside out.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing with "for line in file".  I assumed it would iterate through the file for as long as the function was called with different parameters.

Comment: I'm debating just sticking everything in a list and iterate through that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your function reads from a file with one name, and then writes to a file with a different name. But the names never change, so it keeps using the same input. Try opening the files outside of the function and passing them in.